# How can I make sure nobody is accessing my computer with DameWare or something similar?

Tags: firewalls, remote-desktop

I have a specific need to block any remote connection from DameWare. Can I block a specific port or set of ports in the firewall?

Edit:

I work in IT and my buddy in operations likes to get into my machine and say, change the background when I'm in a meeting! :)

I would like to stop this from happening - I know he used DameWare to accomplish this.
He's using a machine on our network that has DameWare installed to connect to my machine on the network.

Comment: that's exactly what a firewall does - you could simply block all incoming connections

Comment: ok but i assume I can't just blow thru this whole list of ports and block them all without affecting out (maybe critical) systems and processes on my machine, right?  For instance a lot of the file&printer related ports... which I understand is how DameWare uses the Windows API to do it's thing... thru these ports..

http://documentation.dameware.com/dmg/Content/dmg_port_requirements.htm

Comment: I would probably start by asking him to stop, and if he doesn't then let HR know. Because if you block this prank it will become something else.

Comment: "something else" - i have a feeling it's already going in that direction...  I think it's just my personality seems to invite this kind of thing??

Comment: This seems like a problem which needs an interpersonal solution, not a technical one. That makes it more of a problem for https://workplace.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]

Well, your edit makes the question specific to Dameware, rendering the below answer not so useful. In that case, assuming you have the privilege to edit firewall rules (which i doubt a little), you can block the inbound and outbound traffic on the ports used by Dameware.
Here is the list of ports used by dameware: -
http://documentation.dameware.com/dmg/Content/dmg_port_requirements.htm
[Edit End]

**Use wireshark.**
It's a great tool for monitoring your system's **live network related activities**.

You can start wireshark on whatever **interface you are connected** to (like Ethernet or WIFI). It will start capturing each and every packets that leave your system or enter your system ie. **Inbound and Outbound traffic**. While doing that, make sure you are also accessing or using your exposed port like 80, 443 (or other ports that you know are open), reason being I have seen many **malwares that lie dormant** and are only triggered when user do some activity, so that it can **hide it's traffic under user's traffic**.

After doing the capturing for some time stop the capture, save the **pcap** file and you can again **analyze it using wireshark**. It has great filters to help you out of the heap of packets.
Here is a **quick start guide** for it: - http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/

Assuming that you do find something suspicious, you can mitigate them accordingly.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46531/discussion-on-answer-by-7h1n0b1-how-can-i-make-sure-nobody-is-accessing-my-compu).

Answer (score 0):

Dameware is a legitimate admin tool. Your buddy is logging in with an Admin password and using what I assume to be a sanctioned tool.

Stopping this might be more difficult than you think.

If you have full admin rights on your machine, you could suspend the Dameware process or write your own rules for the firewall. You could write a rule that blocks all incoming connections and enable/disable it when going into meetings.

When I have used Dameware, there was a [local connection log](http://forums.dameware.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=91) that would show that an admin connected. I'd look for that if you want to have some leverage to get your buddy to stop.

If you do not have permissions to do any of these things, I'm not sure that there is anything you can do through technology.